# CSS3 Animation bounce effect: Combination of Percentage and Pixels

Tags: css, animation

If i give "from" value as a percent and "to" value in pixels, the "bounce animation doesn't work as intended.

Please check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xJ4xy/

What could be the solution? (I try not to use javascript afap)

```
 <style type="text/css">
        @-webkit-keyframes A123 {
            0% {
              top:190px; /* from 190px to 20% doesn't work */
              top: 90%;/* this works */
            }
            100% {
                top:20%;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Your fiddle actually works in Chrome from 190px to 20%. I just tried

Answer (score 0):

Give **position:relative** to your `page-1` class. Then both work same. Write like this:

> .page-1{
>       position:relative; }

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/xJ4xy/1/

Comment: Oh that really worked. But it's still not working in my project file. Will try and let you know.

Comment: that's ok if you want an explanation why this happens. I will explain you :)

Comment: Hi Sandeep, actually.. it's NOT working.
0% {
              top:190px; /* from 190px to 20% doesn't work */
            }
but 
0% {
             
              top: 90%;/* this works */
            }
and it's true even for position:relative for the page-1.